# How can I increase the UDP Buffer of transport provider in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, c++, udp, buffer, liskov-substitution-principle

I've been looking for quite a while how I can increase the UDP Buffer, without a solution.

I have some kind of a Webcam which send over UDP JPEG Images. These are divided by the cam (no MTU fragmentation) in datagram packets of 1024 Bytes. When the Image size gets near 65K, the Image gets erroneous because of lost packets. I think this is because of the maximum message size of 65527(0xfff7) of the UDP Transport Provider, what you can see with SpOrder.exe in the Windows SDK.

I have tried to change this size with the function WSCUpdateProvider from "Ws2_32.dll". I called WSCEnumProtocols to get the UDP transport provider information and WSCGetProviderPath cause it is also needed and I get the information I need, but when I call WSCUpdateProvider (no matter what information are given) with administrative rights, I always get Error: 11003 (WSANO_RECOVERY).

Is there a kind of a trick I missed or something? Do I have no rights to call this function? Do I have to write my own UDP transport provider or is there maybe another solution?

Here my code in C#:

```
private void ConfigUDP(uint p)
    {
        Int32 protocol = 17;
        WSAPROTOCOL_INFO[] info = null;
        UInt32 len = 0;
        Int32 err = 0;
        NativeMethods.WSCEnumProtocols(ref protocol, info, ref len, ref err);
        info = new WSAPROTOCOL_INFO[len/Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WSAPROTOCOL_INFO))];
        Int32 ret = NativeMethods.WSCEnumProtocols(ref protocol, info, ref len, ref err);
        for (int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
        {
            if (info[i].iProtocol != 17)
            {
                continue;
            }
            Int32 pLen = 255;
            StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(pLen);
            NativeMethods.WSCGetProviderPath(ref info[i].ProviderId, path, ref pLen, ref err);
            WSAPROTOCOL_INFO[] newInfo = new WSAPROTOCOL_INFO[1];
            Array.Copy(info, i, newInfo, 0, 1);
            //newInfo[0].dwMessageSize = (UInt32) p;
            int rs = NativeMethods.WSCUpdateProvider(ref info[i].ProviderId, ref path, newInfo, 1, ref err);
            Console.WriteLine(new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
            Console.WriteLine(new Win32Exception(err).Message);
        }
        ret = NativeMethods.WSCEnumProtocols(ref protocol, info, ref len, ref err);
        for (int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info[i].dwMessageSize);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN
    {
        public Int32 ChainLen;                                                                  /* the length of the chain,     */
                                                                                                /* length = 0 means layered protocol, */
                                                                                                /* length = 1 means base protocol, */
                                                                                                /* length > 1 means protocol chain */
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 7)]   /* a list of dwCatalogEntryIds */
        public UInt32[] ChainEntries;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct WSAPROTOCOL_INFO
    {
        public UInt32 dwServiceFlags1;
        public UInt32 dwServiceFlags2;
        public UInt32 dwServiceFlags3;
        public UInt32 dwServiceFlags4;
        public UInt32 dwProviderFlags;
        public Guid ProviderId;
        public UInt32 dwCatalogEntryId;
        public WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN ProtocolChain;
        public Int32 iVersion;
        public Int32 iAddressFamily;
        public Int32 iMaxSockAddr;
        public Int32 iMinSockAddr;
        public Int32 iSocketType;
        public Int32 iProtocol;
        public Int32 iProtocolMaxOffset;
        public Int32 iNetworkByteOrder;
        public Int32 iSecurityScheme;
        public UInt32 dwMessageSize;
        public UInt32 dwProviderReserved;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string szProtocol;
    }

    internal class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Int32 WSCUpdateProvider(ref Guid lpProviderId, ref StringBuilder lpszProviderDllPath, WSAPROTOCOL_INFO[] lpProtocolInfoList, UInt32 dwNumberOfEntries, ref Int32 lpErrno);

        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        internal static extern Int32 WSCEnumProtocols(ref Int32 lpiProtocols, [Out] WSAPROTOCOL_INFO[] lpProtocolBuffer, ref UInt32 lpdwBufferLength, ref Int32 lpErrno);

        //Overloaded so I can pass null for iProtocols
        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        internal static extern Int32 WSCEnumProtocols(IntPtr lpiProtocols, [Out] WSAPROTOCOL_INFO[] lpProtocolBuffer, ref UInt32 lpdwBufferLength, ref Int32 lpErrno);

        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        internal static extern Int32 WSCGetProviderPath(ref Guid lpProviderId, [Out] StringBuilder lpszProviderDllPath, ref Int32 lpProviderDllPathLen, ref Int32 lpErrno);
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand.  You have message size of 1024 bytes, yes?  If you are losing messages at some loading that sounds like it may be to transport-layer buffer sizes, you have a problem with flow-control and increasing stack buffer sizes will merely put the problem off.

Comment: I can change the quality of the images and so change the size. If the size goes under 60k there are maybe 10% or less erroneous. I don't really know whether I'm trying to change the right buffer, but I know from the developer of the Webcam that the problem came together with Vista. There was a change in network (I think NDIS) and since then you can't change the buffer size in the registry or something. So it works in WinXP and Linux.